# Conformar una imagen con múltiples imágenes posicionadas - CSS3 HTML5

Tags: html, html5, css, css3, canvas

**Pedido:**

Posicionar los tanques pegados en la máquina, tal como se ve en la imagen.

**Especificaciones**

Los tanques deben ser imágenes separadas, ya que cada uno tendrá un estado.

*Resultado actual:*

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

*Resultado esperado:*

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

---

Este es el código:

```css
.maquina {
     position:absolute;
     right: 210px;
     top: 200px;
    }

.tanque1 {
     position:absolute;
     right: 210px;
     top: 200px;
    }
     
    .tanque2 {
     position:absolute;
     right: 240px;
     top: 217px;
     
     }
     
     .tanque3 {
      position:absolute;
      right: 270px;
      top: 234px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col xs-4">
        <div class="MAQUINA"><img src="http://imgur.com/jpBVqLS"></div>
        <div class="tanque1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png"></div>
        <div class="tanque2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png"></div>
        <div class="tanque3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes las imágenes de la máquina y el tanque publicadas en internet?, de esa manera podría crearte un ejemplo de lo que quieres.

Comment: @Jemonge

http://imgur.com/M0TM9q7 **TANQUE**
http://imgur.com/gIgQ7LY **MAQUINA**

Comment: @nawelittle, bienvenido al sitio, por favor mira este enlace para saber cómo ajustar el tamaño de tus imágenes: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264393/271772](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264393/271772). Te recomiendo además mejorar tu pregunta, no estoy seguro si con este código se pueda replicar lo que quieres. Lee: [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos.

Comment: Hola @MauricioAriasOlave, la pregunta es simple y por lo que estuve investigando , al resultado se llega de esta manera o similar.
Saludos!

Comment: ¿Necesitas que se use un `<canvas>` y javascript o sólo CSS/HTML y esa etiqueta la has agregado arbitrariamente?

Comment: @OscarGarcia la etiqueta la agregue arbitrariamente. No hay problema si se incorpora con js o canvas.

Comment: El primer problema que veo es que mientras que la imagen de los tanques está cortada para no dejar espacios en blanco, la imagen de la máquina contiene muchos espacio transparente alrededor de la máquina en sí. Además, la imagen de la máquina es considerablemente más grande que la de los tanques (no están en la misma escala). Sería muy sencillo si se solucionasen esos dos problemas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya modifique esos errores. http://imgur.com/jpBVqLS   Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema que veo es que en el CSS tienes `.maquina`, pero luego en el código se hace `class="MAQUINA"`, por lo que los estilos no se aplicarán a ese `div` en particular. CSS diferencia las mayúsculas y minúsculas en nombres de clase e ID (si funcionaría en *quirck mode*, pero no sé si ése es el caso).

Modificando la clase de "MAQUINA" a "maquina" y ajustando la posición de top y right se puede obtener el siguiente resultado que es parecido a lo que buscas:

```css
.maquina {
  position: absolute;
  right: 150px;
  top: 138px;
}

.tanque1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 210px;
  top: 200px;
}

.tanque2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 240px;
  top: 217px;
}

.tanque3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 270px;
  top: 234px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col xs-4">
  <div class="maquina"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jpBVqLS.png"></div>
  <div class="tanque1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png"></div>
  <div class="tanque2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png"></div>
  <div class="tanque3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png"></div>
</div>
```

Pero que deja en evidencia otros problemas que hay:

- Las imágenes no tienen el mismo tamaño, o mejor dicho, no están a la misma escala.
- Provees dos imágenes diferentes de la máquina: una [demasiado grande y con muchos espacios en blanco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeSo9.jpg), y otra [cortada correctamente pero demasiado pequeña](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXz19.jpg).

Voy a cambiar el código un poco más para ponerte un ejemplo que funcionará igual independientemente del número de tanques que tenga la máquina, y que limpia un poco el código HTML para que no se vea excesivo. La idea es sólo usar `div` con las imágenes de fondo y darles diferente posicionamiento dependiendo de cuántos haya (con `nth-child`).

En este ejemplo puedes ver cómo funciona para máquinas de 1 a 5 tanques:

```css
.contenedor-maquina {
  position: relative;
  min-height:300px;
}

.contenedor-maquina>div {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
}

.maquina {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/jpBVqLS.png);
  width: 150px;
  height: 186px;
  right: 115px;
  top: 105px;
}

.tanque {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png);
  width: 91px;
  height: 104px;
}

.tanque:nth-child(2) { right: 210px; top: 200px; }
.tanque:nth-child(3) { right: 240px; top: 217px; }
.tanque:nth-child(4) { right: 270px; top: 234px; }
.tanque:nth-child(5) { right: 300px; top: 251px; }
.tanque:nth-child(6) { right: 330px; top: 268px; }
```

```html
<div class="col xs-4 contenedor-maquina">
  <div class="maquina"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
</div>

<div class="col xs-4 contenedor-maquina">
  <div class="maquina"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
</div>

<div class="col xs-4 contenedor-maquina">
  <div class="maquina"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
  <div class="tanque"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hice varias modificaciones, lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1. Cambié `left` por `right`, cosa que no es necesaria, es cuestión de gustos.
2. Reemplacé las clases `tanque1`, `tanque2`, y demás, por `tanque`.
3. Metí cada `div` adentro del otro.
4. Cambié a la clase `tanque`, por una posición **relativa** en vez de **absoluta**, a excepción de `maquina`, que es `absolute`. Esto hace que cada tanque se mueva siempre igual respecto a la etiqueta padre (la que la contiene).

Luego de todo esto, empecé a ajustar los valores en píxeles hasta que quede bien.

Además puse una clase nueva, llamada `acomodar`. Es invisible, no contiene nada, pero sirve para arrastrar desde `maquina` los tres tanques dependiendo de la cantidad de pixeles dados.

Nota: Cambié la imagen de la *máquina* porque tenía mucho relleno.

```css
.maquina {
    position:absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 10px;
}
.acomodar{
    position:relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: -25px;
}
.tanque{
    position:relative;
    left: -50px;
    top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col xs-4">
 <div class="maquina"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWk5v.png">
  <div class="acomodar">
   <div class="tanque"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png" />
    <div class="tanque"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png" />
     <div class="tanque"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0TM9q7.png.png" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Por que meter los tanques unos dentro de otros? No tiene sentido cambiar la estructura html para eso

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Es la única manera que se me ocurre por ahora.